# Android ProGuard Building a signed apk fails with gradle plugin 3.0.1 (4.1?)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

ProGuard keeps giving errors and not letting me build a signed APK:
[(full console output)](https://pastebin.com/raw/jDCkKtdY)

Red lines:

---

```
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$20$1: can't find referenced field 'android.widget.RadioGroup val$dialogReport' in program class com.package.name.MainActivity$20
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$20$1: can't find referenced field 'android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog val$dialog' in program class com.package.name.MainActivity$20
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$20$1: can't find enclosing method 'void onShow(android.content.DialogInterface)' in program class com.package.name.MainActivity$20
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$8$1: can't find referenced method 'int access$1100()' in program class com.package.name.MainActivity
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$8$1: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap access$1200()' in program class com.package.name.MainActivity
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$8$1: can't find referenced class com.package.name.MainActivity$DeleteSpotTask
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$8$1: can't find referenced class com.package.name.MainActivity$DeleteSpotTask
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$8$1: can't find referenced class com.package.name.MainActivity$DeleteSpotTask
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$8$1: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap access$1500()' in program class com.package.name.MainActivity
Warning: com.package.name.MainActivity$8$1: can't find referenced method 'void access$1600(com.package.name.MainActivity)' in program class com.package.name.MainActivity
```

[My build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/raw/rVRnpUih)

And my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This started happening after updating `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`.

Compiles without any errors when it is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`

Comment: Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead. Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. 

Correct your Source

Comment: This should not be the case, because gradle compiles normally when building a debug apk

Answer (score 1):

Goto gradle-wrapper.properties file in gradle section

change the distributionUrl,

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```